# VB 2010: How to copy all subfolders of a folder to another folder?

Tags: vb.net, directory

I got a question in Visual Basic 2010: How can I copy all subfolders (only the subfolders, not the main folder) into another folder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to recursively iterate through all the files and folders and copy them. This method should do the job for you:

```
Public Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destinationPath As String)
    Dim sourceDirectoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sourcePath)

    ' If the destination folder don't exist then create it
    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(destinationPath) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath)
    End If

    Dim fileSystemInfo As System.IO.FileSystemInfo
    For Each fileSystemInfo In sourceDirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos
        Dim destinationFileName As String =
            System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileSystemInfo.Name)

        ' Now check whether its a file or a folder and take action accordingly
        If TypeOf fileSystemInfo Is System.IO.FileInfo Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName, True)
        Else
            ' Recursively call the mothod to copy all the neste folders
            CopyDirectory(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: WOW! This absolutely works very fine!! Thank you very much!! You saved the evening ;)

Answer (score 2):

System.IO has two classes that you can use in a recursive fashion to do this all from code.

- DirectoryInfo
- FileInfo

DirectoryInfo has two methods that are relevant:

- GetDirectories
- GetFiles

FileInfo has a CopyTo method

Given those objects and methods and a bit of creative recursion you should be able to copy the stuff fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the simplest solution:

```
For Each oDir In (New DirectoryInfo("C:\Source Folder")).GetDirectories()
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(oDir.FullName, "D:\Destination Folder", overwrite:=True)
Next oDir
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Line:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(txtSourceDirectory.Text, txtDestinationDirectory.Text, True)
```

Comment: How is that different from [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50427990/6045800)? The question asks to copy ***all*** subfolders so Steve's approach makes sense. Does your 1 line copies all folders, or just one?