# Copy subfolder of a subfolder that belongs to a subfolder VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, foreach

how do I copy a subfolder that has a subfolder that has a subfolder too, do I have to loop to all of that subfolders? if it is then does it mean I have to do like this?

```
    For Each sf In Directory.GetDirectories(src)
        For Each sf2 In Directory.GetDirectories(sf)
            For Each sf3 In Directory.GetDirectories(sf)
                For Each sf4 In Directory.GetDirectories(sf3)
                    'execute
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

what if this case is repeated many times? like, the subfolders are more than 10. does it mean I have to a write that code 10 times?

Comment: Sounds about right ;)  Of course, you can always do it recursively, which allows you to go down any arbitrary folder depth (until you run out of stack space) )

Comment: what do you mean I can do it recursively?

Comment: Already answered here I think. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525573/vb-2010-how-to-copy-all-subfolders-of-a-folder-in-an-other-folder

Comment: Recursively: you call A inside of A till A reaches termination condition. If termination condition is reached the A return its evaluation result to the A who calls it till the return reaches the original caller.

Comment: @CrushSundae wew you saved my life again. Thanks! =)

Comment: _Again_? O.o But welcome though.

Comment: Ahh.. It's you! It's you! Now I remember, sorry. :) Goodluck on your project.

Comment: @CrushSundae may I know your name sir if it's okay? cuz I'm a Filipino too. =)

Comment: Just give me your email then I'll just add you on Facebook. :)

Comment: @CrushSundae skyscraper11@ymail.com this is my email sir, Thanks! =)

Comment: Request sent. Now let's stop making these comments section a chat box. Moderators will be mad at us. Have a nice day bro.